# how can i existing android flutter project in ios? do i need to do any changes in code in vs?

Tags: flutter

**created flutter project and running in android easily** but *how can we run in mac* and
< what code we need to change and implement?>

---

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac device to run on iOS. By selecting a simulator, you can easily run from vscode/android studio/xcode. Also you don't need to change any code but if you want to show different style in different platform, you need to change those code accordingly.